# Trouble with create function in django using rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am a Flask developer using Django for a project I am working on... I am using rest framework in django because I am using firebase for auth and found some good advice on how to incorporate it using rest framework

Problem is when I try to create a supplier for a user, you can see the error response from Postman below...

Request to: http://localhost:8000/pm/createsupplier/3/

Request body:

```
{
    "supplier": {"name": "Donald Duck", "phone": 111, "email": "donald@yahoo.com"}
}
```

Request response:

```
  {
        "email": "kbess86@gmail.com"
  }
```

And the supplier is not created

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Supplier(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField()
```

views.py:

```
class createsuppliers(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateSupplierSerializer
    lookup_field = 'user'
```

serializers.py:

```
class CreateSupplierSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    email = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    phone = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    def create(self, instance, validated_data):
        supplier_data = validated_data.pop('supplier')
        supplier = Supplier.objects.create(user=instance, **supplier_data)

        return supplier
    class Meta:
        model=Supplier
        fields=['name','email','phone']
```

Comment: what does `print(validated_data)` output if you put it above `supplier_data =` in the Serialize create- is it empty?- is it even getting hit?- just throwing debugging ideas out

Comment: Your URL seems more like a view of a specific supplier instead of where you should post the creation of a new supplier.

Comment: That is the problem, it is printing {} an empty dict. I am passing the data as JSON/raw in postman. I also updated my function name to update from create, and am using put on the request. Error receiving is keyError validated_data["supplier"]

Comment: @Jarvis Well I need to get a user's profile to put a supplier under the user model, it is a foreign key.

Comment: Okay… so you are saying the 3 in the URL is mapped to a user. Odd structure for the URL, but not a concern if it is working well. Also, in your question you say you will show the output from Postman, but I don’t see it. If you have updated your code, you should update your post to the updated version. Show the full error message… routing could be important… did you attempt to print the `validated_data` object as suggested in the first comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution...

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Supplier(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
```

views.py...

```
class createsuppliers(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateSupplierSerializer
    lookup_field = 'user'
```

serializers.py...

```
class CreateSupplierSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=200)
    phone = serializers.IntegerField()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if str(self.context['request'].user) != str(instance.user.username):
            raise exceptions.PermissionDenied('You do not have permission to update')
            
        supplier = Supplier.objects.create(user=instance, **validated_data)

        return supplier
    class Meta:
        model=Supplier
        fields=['name','email','phone']
```